# Inverted comma - php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Consider this line of JavaScript

```
str += "onclick=runTest(" +  field + "," + atom[0] + ",'" + atom[1] + "');
```

In the browser, it renders as:

```
onclick="runTest(104,213,'Orsan" Miller');
```

There is an inverted comma between Orsan and Miller although in fact there was not any inverted comma, it's causing a bug.

```
atom[1] = Orsan Miller
```

'Orsan Miller' comes from DB query in PHP.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: An "inverted comma" is also known as a quotation mark :P

Comment: is your first line of javascript a typo or are you really missing the closing quote?

Comment: @brianreavis And if you lived in Britain, you'd call it an "inverted comma".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some quotation marks and escaping... try this:

```
str += "onclick=\"runTest(" +  field + "," + atom[0] + ",'" + atom[1] + "')\"";
```

I prefer to use single quotes for readability, but that's just me:

```
str += 'onclick="runTest(' + field + ',' + atom[0] + ',\'' + atom[1] + '\')"';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str += "onclick=runTest(" +  field + "," + atom[0] + ",'" + atom[1] + "')";
```

Is what you are looking for, it was fine except you forgot the final double quote.